# Why does this JavaScript code run slower after Node.js optimization

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, optimization, v8

I was creating a solution to an [ICPC](https://icpc.baylor.edu/) problem using JavaScript and [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) when I ran into an interesting issue: under certain circumstances my program would run twice as slow on the same data set.

I stripped it down until I got to this minimal example that demonstrates the behavior:

```js
function solve(arr) {
  const total = arr.reduce((a, c) => a + c, 0);
  const count = arr.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < total; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < count; j++) {
      // calculate some stuff
    }
  }
}

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  // generate some sample data (array of 5000 random numbers 1-10)
  const data = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
    data.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1);
  }

  const start = new Date();
  solve(data);  // run solve on the data
  console.log(`${i + 1}: ${new Date() - start}ms`);
}
```

This is the output of running `node --trace-opt code.js` using `Node` v10.15.1:

```js
[marking 0x005062b82521 <JSFunction solve (sfi = 000001DA56AD8CD9)> for optimized recompilation, reason: small function, ICs with typeinfo: 5/7 (71%), generic ICs: 0/7 (0%)]
[compiling method 0x005062b82521 <JSFunction solve (sfi = 000001DA56AD8CD9)> using TurboFan OSR]
[optimizing 0x005062b82521 <JSFunction solve (sfi = 000001DA56AD8CD9)> - took 1.453, 0.702, 0.082 ms]
1: 86ms
[marking 0x005062b82581 <JSFunction (sfi = 000001DA56AD8BD9)> for optimized recompilation, reason: hot and stable, ICs with typeinfo: 22/23 (95%), generic ICs: 1/23 (4%)]
[compiling method 0x005062b82521 <JSFunction solve (sfi = 000001DA56AD8CD9)> using TurboFan]
[optimizing 0x005062b82521 <JSFunction solve (sfi = 000001DA56AD8CD9)> - took 0.159, 0.632, 0.096 ms]
2: 82ms
3: 80ms
[compiling method 0x005062b82581 <JSFunction (sfi = 000001DA56AD8BD9)> using TurboFan OSR]
[optimizing 0x005062b82581 <JSFunction (sfi = 000001DA56AD8BD9)> - took 0.592, 2.312, 0.154 ms]
4: 245ms
5: 243ms
6: 236ms
7: 237ms
8: 240ms
9: 246ms
10: 239ms
```

During the first three iterations the run time is around 80ms, but just before the fourth iteration `Node` recompiles and optimizes a method and from that point on *the code runs about 3 times slower*.

Typically when `Node` does runtime analysis, recompilation, and optimization everything runs faster.

Can anyone explain why `Node` optimization makes things so much worse in this case?

---

Note that if the example code is changed to calculate `total` by iterating instead of using `reduce` the optimization improves performance as expected (run time drops to around 60ms):

```js
let total = 0;
for (let v of arr) total += v;
```

Comment: What about other parts? Maybe this 240ms and some other optimized part runs quicker overall? Perhaps other parallel jobs got a lot faster so 240ms is amortized?

Comment: I think you should report this as a bug, it's certainly unexpected.

Comment: @Bergi good point, didn't realize `Math.random()` excluded `1`, code sample updated.  Good idea, I'll open an issue.

Comment: If you did file a bug report, can you link it please?

Comment: @Bergi `Node` issue [26341](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/26341), `V8` issue [8922](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=8922).  Looks like it is caused by a known compiler issue in `V8` and a fix is currently being tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I filed a bug report and got the [following response](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=8922#c4) from a [Chromium](https://www.chromium.org/) dev:

> Some array builtins used branch hints for loop bounds checks,
>   causing all code after the inlined builtin to become deferred
>   code. This is detrimental for performance.

So it turns out this is a known issue with the `TurboFan` compiler and [a fix has been created](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/c41b66eebbbdb02170cbe38c1b3718eba2742e1c) and is currently being tested:

> This CL removes the
>   hints, which improves code scheduling a lot, on the micro
>   benchmark from the linked bug by 3x.